# parsing a string in javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string in javascript using certain keywords and store my result in an array. For example, i want the string "`coconutmilk`" to be parsed as [`coconut,milk`]. However, I have other keywords, such as "`on`" and "`nut`". I want to prevent the array from being parsed as [coc, on, ut, milk], or [`coco, nut, milk`]. I allow for the array to store values not in my keylist.

I figured regex would be the way to go, but I'm having little luck so far. Any help you can give is much appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why should it not match nut if you search for nut?

Comment: I would be really interested in you regex approach as I cannot imagine how this could be done.

Comment: Ghommey - because I'm looking for the largest match. Maybe another example will clear it up. For a math function, the input arccos14 should be parsed as arccos14, not some value arc times cos(14).

Comment: Felix Kling - Going back to the coconut milk example, my first idea was to use a search and replace on higher precedence words, as RobG mentioned. So "coconutmilk" becomes "[coconut]milk," but I don't know how to avoid searching bracketed off areas. It may be easier to remove the located string, but I dont know how the best way to preserve its order.

Answer (score 0):

Put your keywords in an array in order of precidence (if you want *coconut* to match before *nut*, give it a lower index in the array). Then remove matches as you find them so they don't get matched a second time as sub–strings.

Comment: But how do I preserve the original order of the characters. For example, if I remove coconut, how do I know where it originally was in relation to milk?